# Errors with size on hash value

Tags: ruby, hash

I have some critical error with the hash's size function. This is acting irationnal.

Here is my hash :

```
"questionnaires"=>{"1"=>{"6"=>"8", "7"=>"12", "5"=>"19"}}

@questions=evt["questionnaires"]["1"] # not really "1", that's an id but don't matter here

@questions.each do |(key,question)| # should be "6"=>"8", then "7"=>"12", ect ...
    temp = question.size
```

And results are 1 , 2 , 2. So it is bugging, i am testing with size cause sometimes i get an array like this :

so, i don't know why

```
 "6"=>"8".size == 1, "7"=>"12".size == 2  and "5"=>"19".size == 2.
```

And with this array

```
 "questionnaires"=>{"3"=>{"8"=>{"16"=>"16", "18"=>"18"}}}
```

results are correct. Size = 2, like expected.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 3):

When you have `(key,question)` parameters like you do, they get filled in parallel assignment as it iterates through the hash. So, for example, the first iteration `key` is "6" and `question` is "8". The second iteration, `key` is "7" and `question` is "12".

And you are asking `question.size`. But since `question` is just a String, `question.size` returns the length of the string. The first iteration through, the question id "8" is **1** character long. The second iteration, the question id "12" is **2** characters long. That's where the numbers you are getting are coming from.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, that's really interesting. So, i just need to check if question is a string. I think duck typing is cool, but he can lead to strange cases like this, for newcomers in rails as me :p.

Comment: @perello, it's not often that a variable is ambiguous between a Hash and a String, and even when it is, it's not often that you happen to call a method they both have ('size' in this case). But if you're worried about methods having different meanings with different objects, then just think about operators. The plus sign, for example, has dozens of different meanings depending on its surrounding objects, but that ambiguity doesn't seem like a problem, right?

Comment: Also, if you like my answer, please mark it as "accepted" -- that will give both of us some reputation points, and it will increase your accepted % value.